# I Create a react.js component and it doesn't render

Tags: reactjs

I Create a component and it doesn't render (react js)  < --- completely newbie react js user

first i create well structure of a card in list
meetupitems.js

```js
import { Action } from 'history';
import css from './Meetupitems.module.css';

function Meetupitem(props) {
  <li className={css.item}>
    <div className={css.image}>
      <image src={props.image} alt={props.title} />
    </div>
    <div className={css.content}>
      <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      <address>{props.address}</address>
      <p>{props.description}</p>
    </div>
    <div className={css.actions}>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </li>;
}

export default Meetupitem;
```

then use map() to create card list from "list of data"

Meetuplist.js

```js
import Meetupitem from "./Meetupitems";
import css from "./Meetuplist.module.css";

function Meetuplist(props) {
  return (
    <ul className={css.list}>
      {props.meetups.map((meetup) => (
        <Meetupitem
          key={meetup.id}
          title={meetup.title}
          image={meetup.image}
          address={meetup.address}
          description={meetup.description}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default Meetuplist;
```

and when i'm trying to use it
Allmeetup.js

```js
import Meetupitem from "./Meetupitems";
import css from "./Meetuplist.module.css";

function Meetuplist(props) {
  return (
    <ul className={css.list}>
      {props.meetups.map((meetup) => (
        <Meetupitem
          key={meetup.id}
          title={meetup.title}
          image={meetup.image}
          address={meetup.address}
          description={meetup.description}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default Meetuplist;
```

the result I saw was a blank page at the index route(where the list should show)
but others route was fine
I can't figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is nothing is being returned from your Meetupitem component. There is no **return** statement in it.
I  believe if you look in console in chrome dev tools, you will be able to see the error messages for it.

Try changing it to as shown below:

```
import { Action } from 'history';
import css from './Meetupitems.module.css';

function Meetupitem(props) {
return (
  <li className={css.item}>
    <div className={css.image}>
      <image src={props.image} alt={props.title} />
    </div>
    <div className={css.content}>
      <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      <address>{props.address}</address>
      <p>{props.description}</p>
    </div>
    <div className={css.actions}>
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </li>;
)
}

export default Meetupitem;
```

Comment: Lol i missed a return why i didn't notice this thx!